# System.OverflowException

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, plc

> A first chance exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occured in
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

I am trying to read registers from PLC giving different values from 0 to 65536. However, at any instant, it shows this error and the value becomes 0. Please share your knowledge and tell me why is this happening and how to eliminate this error. Also sometimes i get StackOverflowException. Being a beginner in VB and a noob in programming, I have made this software with much efforts but this is what i got in the end. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
Imports Communication
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Dim plc As PLCEthernetReadWrite
    Dim APP As New Excel.Application
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim SpeedDisplay As Double

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        plc = New PLCEthernetReadWrite("192.168.1.5")
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        plc.writeword("404145", 0)
        workbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        APP.Quit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        MeterCount.Text = plc.ReadWord("404597")
        MeterCount.Text = Val(MeterCount.Text) / 100
        Label4.Text = plc.ReadWord("404141")
        SpeedDisplay = Val(Label4.Text) / 1000
        SpeedDisplay = Math.Round(SpeedDisplay, 1)
        Speed.Text = SpeedDisplay
        Label3.Text = plc.ReadWord("404145")
    End Sub

 Private Sub BrowseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BrowseButton.Click
        Dim myFileDlog As New OpenFileDialog()

        'look for files in the c drive
        myFileDlog.InitialDirectory = "d:\Defects Data"

        'specifies what type of data files to look for
        myFileDlog.Filter = "All Files (*.xlsx*)|*.xlsx*"

        'specifies which data type is focused on start up
        myFileDlog.FilterIndex = 2

        'Gets or sets a value indicating whether the dialog box restores the current directory before closing.
        myFileDlog.RestoreDirectory = True

        'seperates message outputs for files found or not found
        If myFileDlog.ShowDialog() = _
            DialogResult.OK Then
            If Dir(myFileDlog.FileName) <> "" Then
                MsgBox("File Loaded: " & _
                       myFileDlog.FileName, _
                       MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                MsgBox("File Not Found", _
                       MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If

        'Adds the file directory to the text box and Loads the File
        PathTextBox.Text = myFileDlog.FileName
        FilePath = Me.PathTextBox.Text
        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        PieceNoReadLabel.Text = worksheet.Cells(2, 1).Value
        PieceMtrReadLabel.Text = worksheet.Cells(2, 3).Value

        FileVerificationLabel.Text = worksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
        If FileVerificationLabel.Text <> "PieceNo" Then
            MsgBox("Wrong File")
        Else
            MsgBox("Right File")

        End If

        'Getting data from excel file
        DC1.Text = worksheet.Cells(2, 4).Value
        DC2.Text = worksheet.Cells(3, 4).Value
        DC3.Text = worksheet.Cells(4, 4).Value
        DC4.Text = worksheet.Cells(5, 4).Value
        DC5.Text = worksheet.Cells(6, 4).Value
        DC6.Text = worksheet.Cells(7, 4).Value
        DC7.Text = worksheet.Cells(8, 4).Value
        DC8.Text = worksheet.Cells(9, 4).Value

          'Writing  to PLC
        plc.writeword("404518", S1m1.Text)
        plc.writeword("404519", T1m1.Text)
        plc.writeword("404520", S2m1.Text)
        plc.writeword("404521", T2m1.Text)
        plc.writeword("404522", S3m1.Text)
        plc.writeword("404523", T3m1.Text)
        plc.writeword("404524", S4m1.Text)
        plc.writeword("404525", T4m1.Text)
        plc.writeword("404526", S5m1.Text)
        plc.writeword("404527", T5m1.Text)

    Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
        plc.writeword("404217", 1)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        plc.writeword("404217", 0)
        StartButton.Enabled = False
        BrowseButton.Enabled = False
        PathTextBox.Enabled = False
        PathLabel.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

' "404097" , "002071" etc are PLC's register numbers.

'I am also writing even more registers and fetching even more values from excel file, and there are also many if conditions over the values of the 3 registers which i am reading in Timer1_tick event. Like if the value goes above some value, BackColor of a label must change. I cant upload full code due to character limitations. But what i have uploaded is most of the code.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: In Debugger Box @SLaks

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Which line of code throws the error? That would be the most basic starting point. Which variable is overflowing?

Comment: In which *line* do you get the error? Did you try debugging the code? Execution should stop when the exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at AdvancedHMI. It is an HMI toolset for Visual Studio that will take care a lot of  the communication leg work for you. It has a ModbusRTU and ModbusTCP driver.